# Use php namespace inside function

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I get a parse error when trying to use a name space inside my own function

```
require('/var/load.php');

function go(){

  use test\Class;

    $go = 'ok';
    return $go;
}

    echo go();
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_USE in /var/www/test.php on line 8

Comment: Why do you want to do this to begin with? `use` just establishes a file-wide alias name, nothing more, nothing less. What's the point of doing this in a function?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [Scoping rules for importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope)

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the
>   global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the
>   importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be
>   block scoped

So you should put like this, use should specified at the global level

```
require('/var/load.php');
use test\Class;

function go(){
    $go = 'ok';
    return $go;
}
echo go();
```

Check the example 5 in the below manual
Please refer to its manual at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Namespaces have nothing to do with *scope*, so I'd avoid the ambiguous use of that term here...

Comment: @deceze please specify some link for clear understanding of namespaces and scope in php

Comment: ...? You've linked to one: the manual. *Variable scope* and *namespaces* are simply two entirely different concepts.

Comment: @deceze as per my understanding, namespaces are same as 'alias' command in unix, but then why it has only global scope? why cant I define it in a function, with scope limited to that function only? Please help in understanding this

Comment: I suppose because the use of that would be very limited and it would introduce confusion. In one function you `use Foo\Bar as MyClass` yet in another function within the same file you `use Foo\Baz as MyClass`. That easily introduces very confusing little mistakes when reading source code. Therefore `use` directives apply to a whole file/namespace at once. I have yet to encounter a case where this is not sufficient anyway.

Answer (score 6):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):

> The `use` keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations.

Comment: @westnblue It means that a `use` statement can only occur in the part of the code that is run as soon as the file is opened. If you put it inside a class or a function, it would execute when the class or function is invoked. This is incompatible with the PHP system for namespaces and parsing your code, so you have to put the `use` statement in the outermost scope of the file.

Comment: save me the headache of figuring out the problem with my namespace that I put "use" in a function. thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather a lot of people are getting this when including a separate function file and trying to use the static method inside that function.. For example in **index.php**

```
namespace foo/bar
require('func.php')
f();
```

and in **func.php**

```
function f() {
    StaticClass::static_method();
}
```

you simply need to declare namespace foo/bar in **func.php** *(same like how you declared it in **index.php**)* so instead of the above it should look like:

```
namespace foo\bar
function f() {
    StaticClass::static_method();
}
```

to avoid errors like:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'StaticClass' not found in func.php

It's obvious now but I was confused why func.php does not carry over the namespace declaration inside the file that 'requires' func.php