# Why `require` and `use` can not be written in the function body?

Tags: php, namespaces

file1:

```
<?php
    function done() {
        require_once '/home/vendor/autoload.php';
        use Qiniu\Auth;
        use Qiniu\Storage\UploadManager;
        #omitted
        }
?>
```

file2

```
<?php
    require_once '/home/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Qiniu\Auth;
    use Qiniu\Storage\UploadManager;
    function done() {
        #omitted
        }
?>
```

Why file1 can't work?
It should be rewritten as file2, why require and use can be written  in the function body?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586313/php-include-require-inside-functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "use" within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055528/using-use-within-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because  [from php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

for `use` keyword  the same rules apply

In Your case declaring isìnside the function limit the visibilty scope of the vars and code declaread in the included file