# PHP using 'use' in anonymous function throws exception

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I'm working in the latest version of PHP, within a class, and writing a sorting function which includes the following:

```
public static function sort_alphabetically($data, $sortBy=null)
{
    ...

    if($sortBy)
    {
        function sortBy($a, $b) use ($sortBy)
        {
            if ($a->$sortBy == $b->$sortBy){return 0;}
            if ($a->$sortBy > $b->$sortBy){return 1;}
            else{return -1;}
        };

        usort($data, "sortBy");
    }
    return $data;
}
```

yet I'm consistently getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'...

It's difficult to google the word `use` and get useful results, but I have seen a mention that it can't be used within a class or namespace.  However, the PHP documentation does exactly that - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php - so I am not sure whether the author of that bit of the Internet was correct.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  Is there an alternative method I could use?

Comment: If a function has a name, it's not anonymous

Comment: true.  I had overlooked that, thanks

Comment: .. and it's a parse error, not an exception.

Comment: yeah yeah...technicalities... ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use php namespace inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227439/use-php-namespace-inside-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use` keyword is (not the only use case) used to import variables into closures or anonymous functions (other uses are the import of namespaces or traits).

That does not apply to conventional functions that have a name (like in your case). What you did is just nesting a function into another function. In order to be able to import variables into a closure or an anonymous function you need to declare one first.

You have the following options:

```
public static function sort_alphabetically($data, $sortBy=null)
{
    ...

    if($sortBy)
    {
        usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($sortBy){
            if ($a->$sortBy == $b->$sortBy){return 0;}
            if ($a->$sortBy > $b->$sortBy){return 1;}
            else{return -1;}        
        });
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Here you would make use of a closure and import the `$sortBy` variable into it.

```
public static function sort_alphabetically($data, $sortBy=null)
{
    ...

    if($sortBy)
    {
        $callback = function($a, $b) use ($sortBy){
            if ($a->$sortBy == $b->$sortBy){return 0;}
            if ($a->$sortBy > $b->$sortBy){return 1;}
            else{return -1;}        
        };

        usort($data, $callback);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

In this case an anonymous function is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The `use` language construct is valid for anonymous functions only. Your function is not anonymous because you gave it a name.

```
public static function sort_alphabetically($data, $sortBy=null)
{
    ...

    if($sortBy)
    {
        $f = function($a, $b) use ($sortBy)
        {
            if ($a->$sortBy == $b->$sortBy){return 0;}
            if ($a->$sortBy > $b->$sortBy){return 1;}
            else{return -1;}
        };

        usort($data, $f);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Remove the name, you should be fine.

Comment: This won't work because the call to `usort` in your example has no access to the now unammed function. `sortBy` is referenced by name as the second parameter

Comment: Woops, forgot about that.. fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `use` unless it's an anonymous function or closure. Assuming you're not reusing the function elsewhere you can easily adjust your code to suit, as below. Similarly you could assign the function to a variable and use the variable as the second argument of usort

```
public static function sort_alphabetically($data, $sortBy=null)
{
    if($sortBy)
    {
        usort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($sortBy)
        {
            if ($a->{$sortBy} == $b->{$sortBy}){return 0;}
            if ($a->{$sortBy} > $b->{$sortBy}){return 1;}
            else{return -1;}
        });
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

move the function outside of the other function. nesting functions is really hard to read, especially the way you are using the names within this function. it's most likely causing the compiler issue.