# syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a short PHP snippets on top of my blade file

```
<?php


use App\ImageWork, App\User, App\Skill, App\Contact, App\ActivityLog;

$images   = ImageWork::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$users    = User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$logs     = ActivityLog::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$skills   = Skill::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$contacts = Contact::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

?>
```

I got this :

```
syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

when I don't add that line, I got this

```
Class 'ImageWork' not found
```

What should I do now either way is wrong ?

Any hints / suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @aynber that Q&A doesn't have an entry for `T_USE`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ah, okay, I'll withdraw it.

Comment: Is it even possible to use the `use` keyword in Blade templates? Try removing that line and changing `ImageWork::` to `App\Imagework::` etc. Also, this is something you should not be doing in your templates.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this at the top of your blade file rather than being in a controller and then passed through? I can't honestly tell you the answer because the actual code itself looks fine but maybe considering moving it to your controller - if it doesn't work then, we can look at other reasons :)

Comment: A quick googling says that you can't, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227439/use-php-namespace-inside-function

Comment: Why not use `Controller` to do the query job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the DB facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

And try to use that:

```
$images   = DB::table('ImageWork')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Why should he use `DB::table` when he has models

Comment: If it work and the other models don´t get the same error he can isolate the problem to the ImageWork model and find what cause the error in the model.