# How do i use Php Spreadsheet with Fat free to read and edit an excel file?

Tags: php, spreadsheet, fat-free-framework

I need to edit a excel file in php. I've got a simple PHP Spreadsheet.
I use fat-free and the problem is

```
public function MakeExcel()
{

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use \vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet ;
    use \vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx ;
    $Spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $Spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A3', 'toto');
    $writer = new Xlsx($Spreadsheet);
    $writer->save("test.xlsx");


    $f3->set('CONTENT','views/dashboard/dashboard_liste.html');
    $f3->set('CONTENTJS','views/dashboard/dashboard_liste.js');
    echo \Template::instance()->render('views/accueil/accueil.html','text/html');
    $this->db = null;
}
```

use doesn't seem to exist in fat-free so i tried:

```
$f3->use(\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet);
Or
$f3->use("\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet");
and many other it return me the error :
```

> ERROR 500 Call to a member function use() on null

Problem Solved thanks everyone :

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class MakeExcel extends Controller {

```
public function MakeExcel(){

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
}
```

}

Comment: `Use` is a feature of PHP, not of any framework - what makes you think that the first code won't work?

Comment: This : syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use php namespace inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227439/use-php-namespace-inside-function)

Comment: Good to know, then the error is in no way connected to PhpSpreadsheet or that other framework

Comment: i tried 

to put the line before the function iand it seem work he just say file not found now

Comment: Who is "he"? Is there any **clear** error message?

Comment: it sorry "chrome"

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error
Fatal error: MakeExcel cannot use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet - it is not a trait

Comment: Which line throws that error? Do you still have a `use` statement within your function?

Comment: use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

i edit the message to put the new code

Comment: Is this part of another class? Then put the `use` statement at root level, like I've proposed an hour ago

Comment: haaa i thought u said before the function sorry

Comment: it work thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all seems you use Fat Free wrong. Because `$f3` is `null`.

Second. Probably you are importing classes with wrong namespaces. You can read [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of PhpSpreadsheet.

Right way:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

You can phisically find this classes and look on the namespace.
Put your import of composer autoload and use block outside of this function.

Make sure you ran `composet install`

Make your function work without PhpSpreadsheet. And after that try to add other functionality

Comment: Better but still not working :
Fatal error: MakeExcel cannot use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet - it is not a trait

Comment: Did you put your import of composer autoload and use block outside of this function?

Comment: i Have to say i never use composer before im a newbie

Comment: Put `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to index.php for example.
And `use` statement to head of class

Comment: like that ? 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: It's better you read this https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/getting-started

`
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$f3 = \Base::instance();
$f3->route('GET /',
    function() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
);
$f3->run();
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare those files in php top area

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

Then in method create object for spreadsheet

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
```

Then you can define the border and alignment for xls file like that

```
$cell_st =[
     'font' =>['bold' => true],
     'alignment' =>['horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER],
     'borders'=>['bottom' =>['style'=> \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN],'top' =>['style'=> \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN]]
    ];
```

To Define the Header you can use below code

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A2:D2'); 
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A2',  "<YOUR HEADER>");
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:D2')->applyFromArray($cell_st);
```

And Then define the column names

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
         ->setCellValue('A3', 'ID')
         ->setCellValue('B3', 'NAME')
         ->setCellValue('C3', 'CITY')
         ->setCellValue('D3', 'SALARY');
```

After all above code now you can start your content in loop like that

```
    $rowcount = 4;
    foreach($data_array as $key=>$value){
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
         ->setCellValue('A'.$rowcount, $value['id'])
         ->setCellValue('B'.$rowcount, $value['name'])
         ->setCellValue('C'.$rowcount, $value['city'])
         ->setCellValue('D'.$rowcount, $value['salary']);
         $rowcount++;
    }
```

and in last now make object of the Xlsx class to save the excel file

```
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$file_name = "report.xls';
$file_root_path = "assets/reports/xls/".$file_name;
$file_site_path = "localhost/xls_generate/assets/reports/xls/".$file_name;
$writer->save($file_root_path);

// final xls file path is here
echo $file_site_path;
```

That's all, Hope this work for you..

Comment: i understand how to manipulate the file the problem is i can't initialise php spreadsheet it say :

500 Internal Server Error
Fatal error: MakeExcel cannot use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet - it is not a trait

Comment: Please check this trait to manipulate the spreadsheet

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

with below code

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("sample.xlsx");    
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', 'Some value');