# PHPMailer not working when trying to create using a PHP Function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer for sending emails. But I have to write that long code of sending emails on every page. So I thought of trying to put the whole stuff into a function and just calling it whenever I want to make the things dry, simple and easier. But its not working when trying to send emails. I tried the following:

functions.php

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$settings = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings");
$settings-> execute();
$set = $settings->fetch();

function newMail($name, $email, $sub, $msg, $set) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  $mail->Host = $set['set_smtp_host'];
  $mail->Port = $set['set_smtp_port'];
  $mail->SMTPSecure = $set['set_smtp_security'];
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = $set['set_smtp_uname'];
  $mail->Password = $set['set_smtp_pass'];
  $mail->setFrom($set['set_noreply_email'], $set['set_site_name']);
  $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
  $mail->Subject = $sub;
  $mail->Body    = $msg;
  $mail->Send();
}
```

Now I tried calling the function on another page (where functions.php is included) this way:

```
$fname = (!empty($_POST['fname']))?$_POST['fname']:null;
$email = (!empty($_POST['email']))?$_POST['email']:null;

$sub = ''.$title.' - Account Verification Link';
$msg = 'SOME BODY MESSAGE';

if(newMail($fname, $email, $sub, $msg)){
    echo alert_success("Registration successful! Please check your email and click on the activation link to activate your account. If you did not receive any email within 5 minutes then <a href='resend.php'>click here</a> to resend it.");
}else{
    echo alert_success("Registration successful! But unfortunately, we could not send you a verification email. Please <a href='resend.php'>click here</a> to resend it.");
}
```

Here its always returning the else message. Am I wrong coding something here?

Comment: Your function `newMail()` does not return 'true' or 'false', it returns nothing.

Comment: did this code work before make it inside a separated function ?

Comment: yes it works when its outside the function separately

Comment: KIKO Software can you please correct my code to make it work?

Comment: Have a look at the answer that's there, that should work.

Comment: The first problem is, as @KIKOSoftware stated, `newMail()` function returns nothing. The second problem is, you included PHPMailer library outside of `newMail()` function.

Comment: Oh got it.. I just had to put `return` before `$mail->Send()`

Comment: Exactly! :-) It is good practice to always return a value from a function (this is an opinion, not a dictate).

Comment: N'Bayramberdiyev if I place the library inside the newMail() function it return error. It returns this 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in`

Comment: @SuperGENScript Oh sorry.  You aren't sending `$set` variable as a parameter when you execute `newMail()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your function **newMail** at the end by :

```
return   $mail->Send();
```

The send method return true in case the mail is sent , so you function should return this value , if not :

```
if(newMail(...)){ }
```

Will always be false that why the else  case is applied.

```
function newMail($name, $email, $sub, $msg, $set) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  $mail->Host = $set['set_smtp_host'];
  $mail->Port = $set['set_smtp_port'];
  $mail->SMTPSecure = $set['set_smtp_security'];
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = $set['set_smtp_uname'];
  $mail->Password = $set['set_smtp_pass'];
  $mail->setFrom($set['set_noreply_email'], $set['set_site_name']);
  $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
  $mail->Subject = $sub;
  $mail->Body    = $msg;
  return $mail->Send();  // add return here 
}
```

Comment: I firgured it out just seconds before you corrected. But thanks :)

Comment: And can't I put `use PHPMailer` thing inside the function? If placed it returns ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in`

Comment: check here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227439/use-php-namespace-inside-function

Comment: Class definitions are global within a namespace, so there's no need to put `use PHPMailer` inside the function. It could be needed inside the include file.